# How to trigger a function in a stateful widget from another class (when onUnityAdsFinish)?

Tags: flutter, dart, unityads

I have a game screen in a stateful widget that includes a function that lets the player take a step back (undo the previous move). I would like to trigger this function when onUnityAdsFinish() runs from another widget.

Here's the stateful widget on game.dart where the game is played:

```
class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  GameScreenState createState() => GameScreenState();
}

class GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container( 
            // game content here
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          child: Text("Tap Here to Watch Ad to Undo Move"),
          onPressed: () => unityBloc.showUnityAd(),
          // (side note: unityBloc is accessable because I have it declared as "final unityBloc = UnityBloc();" higher up the widget tree on app.dart.)
        ),
      ],
    ),                  
  }

  // This is the function I want to call after the ad is finished.
  void undoMove() {
    setState(() {
      // code to undo move
    });
  }
}
```

When the button is pressed to watch the ad, it calls the showUnityAd() function in my UnityBloc class on unity_bloc.dart:

```
import 'package:unity_ads_flutter/unity_ads_flutter.dart';

class UnityBloc with UnityAdsListener {
...
  showUnityAd() {
    UnityAdsFlutter.show('rewardedVideo').whenComplete(() => null);
  } // called when undo button is pressed on game.dart

  @override
  void onUnityAdsFinish(String placementId, FinishState result) {
    print("Finished $placementId with $result");
    // here is where I want to call the undoMove() function from game.dart
  }
}
```

The ad displays perfectly and the print statement in onUnityAdsFinish prints to the console when the ad is finished, but I can't figure out how to call undoMove at that point.

I have spent all day watching tutorials and reading stackoverflows about callbacks and global keys and such, but I'm just still not getting it.

Can someone please help? How can I trigger the undoMove() function on game.dart when onUnityAdsFinish() fires on unity_bloc.dart? (Or is their another/better way to do this?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a variable that holds a function in the `UnityBloc` class and pass the `undoMove` method to the `showUnityAd` method to assign it to the variable and then you can call it in onUnityAdsFinish method.

So `UnityBloc` becomes this:

```
class UnityBloc with UnityAdsListener {
  void Function() doOnUnityAdsFinish;

  ...

  showUnityAd({@required unityAdsFinishFunction}) {
    ...
    doOnUnityAdsFinish = unityAdsFinishFunction;
  } // called when undo button is pressed on game.dart

  @override
  void onUnityAdsFinish(String placementId, FinishState result) {
   ...
   doOnUnityAdsFinish?.call(); //Only calls if the function is not null
  }
}
```

And you can it in the `MaterialButton`'s `onPressed` like this:

```
 MaterialButton(
          child: Text("Tap Here to Watch Ad to Undo Move"),
          onPressed: () => unityBloc.showUnityAd(unityAdsFinishFunction: undoMove ),   
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be a global/static variable (callback) or a ValueNotifier/Stream.
Maybe, a cleaner approach, would be some package with dependency injection capabilities like ([get](https://pub.dev/packages/get), [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)).

```
class UnityBloc with UnityAdsListener {
  /// pass a callback into the constructor.
  /// Function<String,FinishState> onAdCompleted ;
  /// UnityBloc([this.onAdCompleted]);

  /// easier approach, not very "flexible".
  static Function<String,FinishState> onAdCompleted ;

  showUnityAd() {
    UnityAdsFlutter.show('rewardedVideo').whenComplete(() => null);
  } // called when undo button is pressed on game.dart

  @override
  void onUnityAdsFinish(String placementId, FinishState result) {
    onAdCompleted?.call(placementId, result); 
    // here is where I want to call the undoMove() function from game.dart
  }
}


class GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState(){
     super.initState();
     UnityBloc.onAdCompleted = _onAddCompleted;
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
     super.dispose();
     if( UnityBloc.onAdCompleted == _onAddCompleted) {
         UnityBloc.onAdCompleted = null;
     }
  }

  void _onAddCompleted(String placementId, FinishState result) 
    => print("Finished $placementId with $result"); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container( 
            // game content here
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          child: Text("Tap Here to Watch Ad to Undo Move"),
          onPressed: () => unityBloc.showUnityAd(),
          // (side note: unityBloc is accessable because I have it declared as "final unityBloc = UnityBloc();" higher up the widget tree on app.dart.)
        ),
      ],
    ),                  
  }

  // This is the function I want to call after the ad is finished.
  void undoMove() {
    setState(() {
      // code to undo move
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the package suggestions. Get looks extremely useful!